# How to Extract Value of Output in R?

Tags: r

How can you extract the index value of a result in R.

`data.frame(sort(table(df$col1),decreasing=TRUE))`

This results in an output of the col1 value and its count.
The output is the following:

```
          Var1   |    freq
   ---------------------------
    1     ABC    |      10
    2     DEF    |       9
   ...
```

I'm basically trying to extract 'ABC'.

---

UPDATED ANSWER:

The following options will output the greatest reoccuring value in a column (col1) while retaining the original datatype:

```
subset(df,!is.na(df$col1),) %>% count(col1) %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% c(1)[1][[1]]
OR
data.frame(sort(table(df$col1),decreasing=TRUE))[1,1]
OR
sqldf("SELECT COUNT(*) as count, col1 FROM df WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY col1 ORDER BY count DESC")$col1[1]
```

Comment: Still not sure how to incorporate the which statement into either of these operations

Comment: See edit. Hopefully this clarifies the problem. Thanks

Comment: You seem to want the the most common `col1` value in `df`. Try `names(sort(table(df$col1, decreasing = TRUE)))[1]`

Comment: Using your example, it is possible in a oneliner, `data.frame(sort(table(df$col1),decreasing=TRUE))[['Var1']][1]`, but going straight to the `names` is cleaner than converting the table to a data frame.

Comment: (Btw, "index" usually means the row or column number. E.g., in `a, b, c, d, e`, the index of `b` is 2. It seems like you want the *value*, not the *index*.)

Comment: I tried which.max(table(dat$col1)) and data.frame(sort(table(df$col1),decreasing=TRUE))[['Var1']][1]. Both resulted in an output that I was expecting (col1 value), but the result was an 'integer' so I assume the output was actually referring to the index of the dataframe which is not col1 in my case. I tried names(sort(table(df$col1)))[1]. This resulted in a 'character' output which is what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: you don't need to sort, eg. `names(which.max(table(df$col1)))`

Comment: Thanks jenesaisquoi. I typically work in python so I'm still getting used to R. Wasn't aware of the 'names' function, nice to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to extract the values single column using **dplyr package**, you can use `select`. E.g- `df%>%count(col1)%>%arrange(desc(n))%>%select(col1)`

To find out the index of any column/attributes & index of values in a column, you can use `which`, this syntax need a logical operator and single value. E.g.- `which(colnames(df) == 'column_name'), this gives you the index of that column.

For finding the index of any values of that column, this can be used `which(df$col1 == 1`

Comment: Works up to the 'select(col1)' statement. Tells me I have an unused argument ('col1'). This is what I have: df %>% count('col1') %>% arrange(desc(freq)) %>% select(col1)

Comment: are you using inverted commas in for col1 in any argument?? In dplyr, you don't need to use inverted commas for a column name.

Comment: Okay, that was the problem. So now I have a tibble output. Is there another operation I can add with a pipe operator after the select statement to select a specific index value. Say I want the 5th value in that tibble?

Comment: Got it. Dont know if its the best way but it works: df %>% count (col1) %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% c(1)[1]. Thanks alot for this suggestion. I was looking for something that would also keep the data type of the column. Using the 'names' function outputs a character type unfortunately. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Works for any data type, as long as you have no NA values (which you can just subset out).

Answer (score 1):

Since the result of `data.frame()` is a data frame, one can immediately use the extract operator on it.

```
# generate the data
x <- c(rep("ABC",10),rep("DEF",9))

# extract string with highest frequency from table 
data.frame(sort(table(x),decreasing=TRUE))[1,1]
```

... and the result:

```
> data.frame(sort(table(x),decreasing=TRUE))[1,1]
[1] ABC
Levels: ABC DEF
>
```

One can use `as.character()` to remove the factor levels from the result.

Based on the comments there is a need to obtain counts for numeric variables, and then use the original numeric value to subset the original data frame.

Here is a solution that handles the additional requirement, using the `sqldf` package.

```
# SQLDF solution
library(sqldf)
x <- data.frame(V1=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,8)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
sqlStmt <- "select V1, count(*) as count from x group by V1"
y <- sqldf(sqlStmt) 

z <- y[y$count == max(y$count),1]
class(z)
```

...and the output.

```
> z <- y[y$count == max(y$count),1]
> class(z)
[1] "numeric"
```

Notice how the class of the final result is still numeric, rather than being converted to a factor or character value.

Comment: This brings up the same issue as previous suggestions. Using this will result in the value of interest, however the actual output will be the index (I believe). Running a 'typeof' on this results in an integer, so I assume it's the index that is the actual output. Specifying 'as.character' accomplishes the same as 'names'. It results in a character type. The only solution that I've found (unless you have another suggestion) that will retain the data type is the one I've updated in the question.

Comment: @user10939484 are you trying to extract "ABC" or 10? From the question, it looks like you wanted to extract "ABC", which is why I posted the answer I did.

Comment: You're correct, however, and I misspoke before, sorry. I thought the updated answer was exactly what I wanted but not quite. Right now, I have about 10 different ways to get the answer that I'm looking for... which is 'ABC', but none of the outputs retain the datatype of the column. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user10939484 - Would you please explain the importance of knowing the original data type of the column? It's not clear from the original question.

Comment: Say I want to use this particular value to subset the dataframe or perform an operation. I set your line of code (or any of the others) equal to a variable 'x'. The following would not then work: subset(df,col1==x,). That's why I'm trying to maintain the original data type. I didn't think I would have this much trouble trying to accomplish this honestly.

Comment: OK, if you're trying to use the original numeric value to subset the data, we can use `sqldf` package to accomplish what you're looking for. I'll post another solution illustrating how you can keep a numeric value numeric after aggregating to counts.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there anything you know that can accomplish what I'm looking for outside of sqldf. I was going to try that if everything else failed. But if it's the only way, than so be it. I feel like this is something R should be capable of very easily. It's extremely simple to do in python.

Comment: So what's the python solution?

Comment: df ['col1'].value_counts().index.values[1]  .This keeps the original datatype of the returned value.

Comment: This gives `z` in a single SQL statement: `sqldf("select V1, max(count) from (select V1, count(*) as count from x group by V1)")$V1` except in the case of ties it only gives one.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi - agreed. The intent of my original answer was solely to illustrate that one could use the extract operator on the the object produced by the OP's original code, not to say that it was the "best" way to process the data. `y <- table(x);names(which(y==max(y)))` extracts the value without using `data.frame()` or a sort, but as is noted in subsequent comments, does not retain the original data type.